# Dump Java will not compile

Tags: java

I did not write this Dump question that should compile and was in a recent Java 8 exam and it gives me problems:

```
class Vehicle {
   String type = "4W";
   int maxSpeed = 100;

   Vehicle (String type, int maxSpeed){
      this.type = type;
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
      }
}

 class Car extends Vehicle {
    String trans;
    Car(String trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
    }

    Car(String type, int maxSpeed, String trans) {
    super(type, maxSpeed);
    this(trans);
    }
 }

 class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Car c1 = new Car("Auto");
Car c2 = new Car("4W", 150, "Manual");
System.out.println(c1.type + " " + c1.maxSpeed + " " + c1.trans);
System.out.println(c2.type + " " + c2.maxSpeed + " " + c2.trans);

    }

}
```

The answer according to the Dump should be:

```
4W 150 Manual
```

Instead I get:

```
Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Implicit super constructor Vehicle() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
    Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
```

What am I doing wrong on my end?

Comment: It is correct only for `c2`,  for  `c1` there is no such constructor. Remove lines with `c1` and your are fine.

Comment: @MaxZoom Since he says this is a question from the school. I think he is required to write the classes. He probably is not expected to change anything in  the main().

Comment: In that case there should be two lines printed, but there is only one.

Comment: Since there are2 print lines, OP probably missed out one of the expected output.

Comment: Maybe the dump is wrong and the right answer is that it does not compile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your misconception from here..

```
Car(String type, int maxSpeed, String trans) {
    super(type, maxSpeed);   //cannot use super() & this() concurrently
    this(trans);             //cannot use super() & this() concurrently
}
```

Java do not allow `super()` and `this()` to be called concurrently in the same constructor.

`super()` means calling the constructor from the parent class. `this()` means calling another constructor within your own class.

Since those are actually invoking constructor, thus they need to be at the first line of code.

So, you can only either call `super()` or `this()`. You cannot have both in the same constructor. If it is allowed, you are basically calling the constructor twice and when that happens, ambiguity arises.

Which constructor shall your class use?

Answer (score 3):

This constructor is the problem:

```
Car(String trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
}
```

There's only one constructor in Vehicles, and it takes two arguments.  You don't have a default constructor.  So when you call the Car constructor with only one argument, the compiler looks for a default constructor that doesn't exist.

You can fix it by either adding a default constructor; something like this:

```
class Vehicle {

   public static final String DEFAULT_TYPE = "4W";
   public static final int DEFAULT_SPEED = 100;
   protected String type;
   protected int maxSpeed;

   Vehicle() {
      this(DEFAULT_VEHICLE_TYPE, DEFAULT_SPEED);
   }

   Vehicle (String type, int maxSpeed){
      this.type = type;
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
   }
}
```

Or do this:

```
Car(String trans) {
    super(trans, Vehicle.DEFAULT_SPEED);
    this.trans = trans;
}
```

Comment: @MaxZoom, I rolled your edit back.  I wrote it the way I did deliberately.  Don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the complete code that your school expect from you.

Calling default constructor `Vehicle()` will automatically invoke `Vehicle(String, int)` because of `this("4W", 100)`.

```
class Vehicle {
   String type;
   int maxSpeed;

    Vehicle (){
        this("4W", 100);   //Set your default values here..
    }
    Vehicle (String type, int maxSpeed){
      this.type = type;
      this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Your Car class:

The `super()` can be left out as well because even if you do not include that, it is implicitly called for you.

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
    String trans;

    Car(String trans) {
        super();   //Optional
        this.trans = trans;
    }

    Car(String type, int maxSpeed, String trans) {
        super(type, maxSpeed);
        this.trans = trans;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4W 100 Auto
4W 150 Manual
```